# Determine which vertexes are inside of a subgraph and which are outside

Tags: python, graph

I have a graph `gee` which looks like this:
[image]

Looking at the subgraph made up of vertexes 2, 3 and 4, it's clear that 1 is on the exterior and all the other nodes are on the interior. Similarly, take nodes 2,4, 5 and it's clear that 7 is on the interior and all else are on the exterior. How can I formally get Python to tell me this is the case? I don't think arguments based on distance, edge crossings or degree will work, as I can see counter-examples just in this small graph.

Specifically I'm wondering if I can create a subgraph: `subgee = gee.subgraph([2,3,4])` and then use an argument for "which nodes of `gee` are inside `subgee`?"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the locations ( x, y ) of the vertices?

To find out if a point is inside a polygon, conceptuality:  draw a line from the point to infinity, count the intersections with the polygon edges, if 0 or even, then point is outside, if odd then point is indide.

This is challenging to implement in code.  Here is some C code that does the counting:

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i testy) != (verty[j] > testy)) 
       if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
            (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```

Some more discussion of this at: https://ravenspoint.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/in-or-out/

Answer (score -1):

I can figure this out by just looking at the edges. In the 2, 4, 5 triangle, 7 is interior because its only edges are to 2, 4 and 5.

```
gee.edges(7)
EdgeDataView([(7, 2), (7, 4), (7, 5)])
```

Comment: neighbors is even more direct

Comment: 7 could be outside the 2,4,5 triangle and still have edges connecting it to 2,4, and 5.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after the fact. Your answer about polygons makes sense. I'm looking for something similar in python